# How to check each letter input against a keyword

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to write a game where users input each letter of a hidden word and a message is show to say if the guess is correct or not. The current page can be viewed at: http://www.kamac.co.uk/wordplay3/#/gamecontrol.

This shows how the game should work but the value of Selected Word and VM Top Secret should be the same value. The reason they are different is because in my code I have had to use 2 different controllers to get everything to work.

The partial HTML is as follows:

```
<section class="spellbound container-fluid">
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>SpellBound</h2>
<p>Below you will see a definition of one of the words in the dictionary. Enter a correct letter and the square turns green - enter a wrong letter and it turns red.</p>
```

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading">How do you spell the word that means</div>
<div class="panel-body">{{selectedDefinition}}</div>    
<p>Selected Word: {{selectedWord}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-controller="GamecontrolController as vm">
<p>VM Top Secret: *{{vm.topsecret}}*</p>
<input type="text" width="1" ng-model="vm.letter[$index]" ng-repeat="letter in vm.topsecret track by $index" ng-change="vm.checkLetter($index)"/>
<p><span>{{vm.result}}</span></p>
</div>

<div>
<a ng-click="reloadPage()"  class="btn btn-info btn-lg" role="button">Play Again</a>
<a href="#/home" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" role="button">Back To Menu</a>
</div>

</section>
```

The controller code is as follows:

```
wordplayControllers.controller('SpellboundController', function ($scope, $http){
var vm = this;

$http.get('data/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.entries = data;
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.entries.length);

    $scope.selectedWord = $scope.entries[rand].word;
    $scope.selectedDefinition = $scope.entries[rand].definition;

    vm.topsecret = $scope.selectedWord;
    vm.letter = [];

    vm.checkLetter = function(index){
        if(vm.topsecret[index] === vm.letter[index]){
            vm.result = "letter was correct"
        } else {
            vm.letter[index] = "";
            vm.result = "nope";
            }
        }   
    });     

});
```

Somehow I need to have my dictionary of words, select a word, display the necessary number of input boxes and finally check the input of entry into the boxes all in a single controller. I have been wrestling with this problem for a while now and previous help from this forum has allowed me to get it this far but there is obviously something wrong in my interpretation of how AngularJS works. I would really be grateful for some help in finally resolving this particular issue (and understanding the solution).

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of doing this?

```
 vm.topsecret = $scope.selectedWord;
```

you can simply get rid of

```
<div ng-controller="GamecontrolController as vm">
```

and attach everything to $scope , it should work.

Comment: I agree that the answer should be to attach everything to $scope but my problem I can't get the syntax correct to do so.

So in the HTML I remove the outer div and change the input to <input type="text" width="1" ng-model="letter[$index]" ng-repeat="letter in selectedWord track by $index" ng-change="checkLetter($index)"/>
  <p><span>{{result}}</span></p>

Would that be correct for this side of things ?

I have done this on http://www.kamac.co.uk/wordplay3/#/spellbound and tried to update the controller accordingly but you can see that it does not work.